# Apache returning incorrect mime type for meta-data.xml.md5

Tags: apache-2.2, mime-type

I'm struggling to get apache2 to serve a file with the correct mime type. I'm using an installation of apache 2.2 installed with apt-get on Ubuntu.

The file in question is a maven repository file called `maven-metadata.xml.md5`.

For some reason apache is insisting this is of type  `Content-Type: application/xml`  This is clearly incorrect since the entire content of the file:

```
443219553065c4885947185d40d2a04e
```

I can only assume this decision is being made by apache because of "xml" in the file name, but it makes no sense in context.

I've tried adding `md5` to `/etc/mime.types` as `text/plain` but I still get the same result.

The full headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Dec 2014 22:58:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 14:56:57 GMT
ETag: "6e8e3cb-20-50a7ecdb68040"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 32
Keep-Alive: timeout=30
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**  I think I may have missed an obvious step like restarting the server after adding `md5` to `/etc/mime.types`.

Comment: My guess is that apache is incorrectly deciding that MD5 is a [Content-encoding](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) (see also: the rest of the page about how mod_mime handles multiple extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to DerfK for pointing me to the right page:

It turns out this Apache is acting exactly as designed. It allows for multiple extensions and simply picks the right most extension that it recognises.

This can be read about here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext

The solution was to add `md5` against `text/plain` in `/etc/mime.types`.  **Then restart apache so that it recognises the change.**